# How to adjust orientation of camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why is the projection not on the XY plain?

[image: image description]

```
<sensor name='camera1' type='depth'>
  <visualize>1</visualize>
  <pose>-0.1 0 0.2 0 0 0</pose>
  <camera name='head'>
    <horizontal_fov>1.39626</horizontal_fov>
    <image>
      <width>800</width>
      <height>800</height>
      <format>R8G8B8</format>
    </image>
    <clip>
      <near>0.02</near>
      <far>300</far>
    </clip>
    <save enabled='0'>
      <path>/tmp</path>
    </save>
    <depth_camera>
      <output>depthImage</output>
    </depth_camera>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <mean>0</mean>
      <stddev>0.007</stddev>
    </noise>
  </camera>
  <plugin name='plugin_1' filename='libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so'>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
    <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
    <pointCloudTopicName>pointCloud</pointCloudTopicName>
    <depthImageTopicName>pointlCloudImage</depthImageTopicName>
    <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>camera1_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
    <colorImageTopic>/camera/rgb/image_color</colorImageTopic>
    <depthMapTopic>/camera/depth_registered/image_rect</depthMapTopic>
    <cameraName>camera1</cameraName>
    <frameName>camera_frame</frameName>
    <pointCloudCutoff>0.001</pointCloudCutoff>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101321/how-to-adjust-orientation-of-camera/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be better at http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/ but still...

This is because you use "camera_frame" and not "camera_frame_optical". See the standard frame orientation in [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-19**:
FYI --     I changed my references to camera_frame_optical and it do not make a difference. I am getting close to a solution if nothing else I will translate in code.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-19**:
I suggest you use `rosrun tf view_frames` to see the relative orientation of both frames. Maybe this is a re-orientation issue.